# Javascript - creating a new Array method

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I would like to extend the Javascript built-in Array object by addind a new method:   `searchByRegexp`

Basically the method will get a regexp as input and will return:
_ a string representing the element of the array that matches the regexp (if more than one match, the first one will be returned)
_ an empty string if none of the elements matches the regular expression.

Comment: What is blocking you ? Adding a function to the prototype, doing that specific function ... ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Just for interest or maybe convenience there are libraries which already do this. See [`Enumerable.grep`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/grep/) for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick and dirty ([fiddle for your fiddling pleasure](http://jsfiddle.net/eBtgA/)):

```
Array.prototype.searchByRegexp = function (rx) {
    for(var i = 0, ln = this.length; i < ln; i++) {
        // test item i
        if(rx.test(this[i])) {
            return this[i] + "";
        }
    }
    // return an empty string if no matches are found
    return "";
}
```

However, you may wish to implement [more *general* methods](http://jsfiddle.net/eBtgA/3/) instead...

```
Array.prototype.find = function(delegate) {   
    for(var i = 0, ln = this.length; i < ln; i++) {
        if(delegate(this[i])){
            return this[i];   
        }
    }
    return null;
}

Array.prototype.findAll = function(delegate) {   
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0, ln = this.length; i < ln; i++) {
        if(delegate(this[i])){
            results.push(this[i]);   
        }
    }
    return results ;
}

Array.prototype.each = function (delegate) {
    for (var i = 0, ln = this.length; i < ln; i++) {
        delegate(this[i], i);
    }
}
```

... which could then perform regex comparison like so:

```
// test values
var sizes = ["Small", "Medium", "Large", "Extra-Large", "Extra-Extra-Large"];

// Print single value or blank
document.write(sizes.find(function(size){
    return /large/i.test(size);
}) || "");     

// horizontal rule to separate our results
document.write("<hr/>");

// Print all matches
sizes.findAll(function(size){
    return /large/i.test(size);
}).each(function(size){
    document.write(size + "<br/>"); 
});
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I would like to put all those extra functions in a file. Is there a convension for its name? I mean, for a file extending the prototype of a built-in javascript object.

Comment: I'm not aware of any file-naming conventions for prototype extensions.

Answer (score 4):

As of today, using Google Chrome, the provided solution breaks the iteration over the array.

After `Array.prototype.searchByRegexp = function ...`, if you iterate with `for (var k in arrayInstance)`, the value `searchByRegexp` will be in the keys, not only the real array keys.

To prevent that you should use `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, ...`

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'searchByRegexp', {
    value: function (rx) {
        for(var i = 0, ln = this.length; i < ln; i++) {
            // test item i
            if(rx.test(this[i])) {
                return this[i] + "";
            }
        }
        // return an empty string if no matches are found
        return "";
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```